# Making an image + container height not exceed 100vh units in a flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, background-size, viewport-units

I'm making a typical mobile app showcase one-page, and I'm having trouble trying to make the app screenshot examples fit inside a container with a smartphone outline background and THEN having the 2 of them not exceed the viewport height (the particular section I'm working on has a height of 100vh).

Explained with an image, this is what I'm after:

[image: target]

Been trying things all day long and can't seem to be able to work it out. I understand that my problem lies somewhere with the screenshot container and the img. Since this is flexbox and the parent lays its children in a row, the img container occupies 50% of the width, and its background just fits its height since it has a background-size: contain set. But when the img is rendered, it occupies the 100% of its parent, which is the container, which is 50% the width of its flex container. So, how can I force the image to just adapt its height to its parent and make the width resize as well with the correct aspect ratio?

**HTML**

```
<section>
<div class="section-wrapper">
<div class="section-texts-wrapper">
<div class="section-texts-icon">
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x50" alt="Create">
</div>
<div class="section-texts-content">
<p><strong>This is a subtitle.</strong></p>
<p>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. </p>
<p>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="section-screenshot">
<img src="http://placehold.it/750x1334">
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
html {background-color: #000;}

section {
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;

background-color: #333;
color: #999;
}

.section-wrapper {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
padding: 20px;
height: 100%;
}

.section-screenshot {
background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rn2y4x2zyjuoq0i/phone_outline.svg?dl=0) center top no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
text-align: center;
max-height: 90vh;
}

.section-screenshot img {
width: 70%;
padding: 15% 0 15%;
opacity: 0.6;

}
```

Here is a codepen with the basic layout: https://codepen.io/mrmerrick/pen/KNvRoy

Edit- here are some more visual explanations of what I'm after.

[image: img01]

[image: img02]

[image: img03]

[image: img04]

Answer (score 0):

I think this code solved your problem:

```
.section-screenshot img {
  margin-top: 7.5vh;
  height: 70vh;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.section-screenshot {
  width: auto;
  height: 90vh;
  padding: 2.5vh;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rn2y4x2zyjuoq0i/phone_outline.svg?dl=0) center top no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Now the screenshot image behavior by the **viewport height**. I'm using `margin-top` with `vh` to get the screen in the middle of the phone image and the parent container set by `90vh` `height` (no `max-height` - its not necessary) with auto `width` (because the parent container change by image size) and `padding` (to get space around the image).

---

**Look at this example:**

```css
html {background-color: #000;}

section {
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;

background-color: #333;
color: #999;
}

.section-wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 20px;
 height: 100%;
}

.section-screenshot {
  width: auto;
  height: 90vh;
  padding: 2.5vh;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rn2y4x2zyjuoq0i/phone_outline.svg?dl=0) center top no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

 .section-screenshot img {
  margin-top:7.5vh;
  height: 70vh;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div class="section-wrapper">
  <div class="section-texts-wrapper">
   <div class="section-texts-icon">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x50" alt="Create">
   </div>
   <div class="section-texts-content">
    <p><strong>This is a subtitle.</strong></p>
    <p>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. </p>
    <p>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. </p>
   </div>
  </div>
   <div class="section-screenshot">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/750x1334">
   </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Fixed your **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Wolka/pen/gLxKoX)**

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering. For the most part this works, but it's not a universal solution: try resizing the browser horizontally: when the space is too narrow, the container will shrink down while the image ignores this, overlapping it. I'm looking for a way to somehow make an "always responsive object" that is made of both a container and its image.

Also, I'd really appreciate if you could explain why your solution works in order to understand the underlying technique. Why force a width of 50%? Why is max-height needed on the container if removing it makes no difference? Etc..

Comment: Thanks again! This works better but it's still not a proper responsive solution. Try making the browser window narrow and high: the screenshot has way more width than the area with the texts, when both should be 50% as dictated by its flex parent. There must be some way to solve this with pure CSS. Maybe the container + screenshot combo needs a wrapper for it? This looks very simple but it's a pain to get right :\

Comment: i cant understand what you asking. you need a vh height changing or width changing. you cant handle both because the image ratio. i think the best way is use @media queries around 600px and change the css structure.

Comment: I understand I may have been very sparse with details, sorry about that and thanks again for the help. I've updated the post with some images of what I'm after. I think I'll need a wrapper container for both the screenshot and its smartphone outline container?

Answer (score 0):

Set the image to occupy 100% of the height of the container, and set the width to auto. This will make the image adjust the width to the aspect ratio.

The rest will fit automatically:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
html {
  background-color: #000;
}
section {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #999;
}
.section-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90%;
}
.section-screenshot {
  background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rn2y4x2zyjuoq0i/phone_outline.svg?dl=0) center top no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.section-screenshot img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="section-wrapper">
    <div class="section-texts-wrapper">
      <div class="section-texts-icon">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x50" alt="Create">
      </div>
      <div class="section-texts-content">
        <p><strong>This is a subtitle.</strong>
        </p>
        <p>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-screenshot">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/750x1334">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```